# Scheduled task agent wp7 soap client does not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-agents

I have this:

```
public class ScheduledAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
{
    ...

    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        var userSettings = Utils.LoadSettings();
        try
        {
            var client = new CheckinServiceSoapClient();
            var token = WsApiCaller.Token;
            var point = ... // User Location;
            if (point != null)
            {
                client.UserTrackAsync(token, userSettings.UserId, 
                    point.Latitude, point.Longitude, 
                    point.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy,
                    point.Position.Location.Altitude,
                    point.Position.Location.Speed,
                    point.Position.Location.VerticalAccuracy,
                    point.Position.Location.Course,
                    "BACKGROUND_AGENT");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```

OnInvoke event occurs. But call of UserTrackAsync is not executing.

Comment: If I'd have to hazard a **guess**, I'd say it's because `point` is null, or an utterly swallowed exception is thrown. Have you tried debugging, at all?

Comment: Of course. 
There is no exceptions.

Comment: Then `point` is null?

Comment: No, `point` is specified by user location.
I have add this:

`client.UserTrackCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var res = args.Result.Retval;

                };`

Break point is never access by debuger.

Comment: If `point` is not null and there are no exceptions, then `client.UserTrackAsync` is executing. You're just not getting the expected result, which you haven't detailed. Consider tracing on your soap service.

Comment: The very strange situation. `OnMethodComplete` is not occured.
When web service called by another console program all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `client.UserTrackAsync` is an async call. The problem is that `NotifyComplete();` is executed before `client.UserTrackAsync` has a chance to finish.

You need to call it in the `UserTrackCompleted` handler (and delete it from the original place):

```
client.UserTrackCompleted += (sender, args) => 
{ 
    var res = args.Result.Retval; 
    NotifyComplete();
};
```